# TestCafe chrome:headless intermittently fails with Vue event emit

Tags: vue.js, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe, uitest

- Chrome: Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- TestCafe: 1.14.2

**Vue codes**

Template

```html
<input
  id="amount"
  v-model="amount"
  min="0"
  name="amount"
  class="input-field"
  :placeholder="labelPlaceholder"
  @input="validateAmount"
>
```

Event emitter

```js
validateAmount() {
  ...
  this.$root.$emit('new-amount', this.id, this.valid, this.amount);
},
```

Event receiver

```js
this.$root.$on('new-amount', (id, valid, amount) => {
  if (this.id === id) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.validAmount = valid; // In the screenshot below
  }
});
```

**Test codes**

TestCafe with `chrome:headless` (browser mode works) intermittently fails for tests with Vue event emit. No matter test waits for 2 seconds or not, the result is same but when it enables [Quarantine mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#quarantinemode) it passes (I don't want to use this though)

```js
test('Should be enabled when a valid value is entered', async (t) => {
  await t
    .typeText(amount, '1')
    .expect(amount.value)
    .eql('1');
  await t.wait(2000);
  const after = button.withAttribute('disabled', 'disabled').exists;
  await t.expect(after).notOk();
});
```

**Result TestCafe test (screenshot on error)**

```sh
1) AssertionError: expected true to be falsy
```

[image]

**Result by user (MUST BE)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since enabling the `quarantine mode` fixes the problem, I assume that the issue occurs because sometimes the event is not fired within 2 seconds.
Try to rewrite your code in the following way:

```js
test('Should be enabled when a valid value is entered', async (t) => {
    await t
        .typeText(amount, '1')
        .expect(amount.value).eql('1');
        .expect(button.hasAttribute('disabled')).notOk();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! and I have tested it but it did not work. That is fine, this is not the end. :)